# How can I adjust the QoS settings on a D-Link 2740u router?

Tags: networking, router, qos

I'm having a problem with online games, because when someone in my house open YouTube or other heavy internet demanding apps my game ping skyrockets.

I searched online for a bit I found that can be fixed by using QoS on the router.

I opened the router settings page, found an “IP QoS” settings page, but it doesn't look like any of the tutorials I have watched where the D-Link QoS Engine page looks simpler than what I am seeing.

I was wondering if I can use this page and how can I use it to give my machine the highest priority while the others to lowest

Here’s a screen-shot of the QoS page I am seeing:

[image: D-Link 2740u QoS settings page.]

[image: D-Link 2740u Qos Add-Rule.]

What i want todo is set my device for the highest priority. and the rest to lowest. but im not sure how todo that.

Comment: you add a rule via the `Add Rule` button. How exactly it looks there I obviously can't say but you should be able to select a **service** or **protocol** like "http" or all Network traffic generating from or to a specific host and select a **priority/bandwith**. According to necessity you fill in the other forms like MAC address, Port, etc.

Comment: @NordlysJeger sorry forgot to add a screenshot for that.. uploading one right now

Comment: added the image but not sure how to make it visible or display it

Comment: I just made it visible.

Comment: what options do you have available on "Schedule Mode"

Comment: "Strict Prior" and "WFQ 4:3:2:1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81011/discussion-between-nordlys-jeger-and-noor-nizar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a short list of Values to be inserted into above form:

- Schedule Mode: Strict prior
- Source MAC: Your NICs MAC address
- Dest. MAC: Empty
- Source IP: Your PCs IP
- Source Mask: Your networks subnet mask. Normally it should be 255.255.255.0
- Dest. IP: Empty or 0.0.0.0
- Dest. MAC: Empty
- [...]
- Priority: highest

The rest should be ok if left empty.

Comment: thank you , one more thing tho. what is the default priority. for each device. ? like do i have to set everymachine to lowest ? or are they all already at lowest

Comment: If your router has three priority levels 1-highest, 2-normal, 3-lowest then all other devices/packages are set to level 2. This means if you set your device to level one or highest its traffic is handled before the others, without specified priority level, and if you set it to lowest or level 3 then all unspecified devices/traffic are handled first.

Comment: Yes it does have 3 levels . Is there's any performance difference if I set all the rest to lowest ?

Comment: As long as the rest are all on the same level there will be no difference in performance